# Flux Slider - How to remove the borders/space?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow, flux

I'm using Flux Slider, I added the images and everything works just fine, except that the there are these white spaces/broders that surround the slider from above, left right and bottom.
I tried deleting them by resetting the CSS of the #slider to no border, no padding, no margin but to no avail, any ideas?

Comment: it's a little difficult to figure out without any code - would you mind sharing a snippet